# How can I tell if a file is currently being written to?

Tags: android, file

I'm saving a fairly large bitmap in a background thread. It takes about a second. The main thread will try to load the same file into a canvas. How can I tell the main thread to wait until it has finished saving?

### Edit:

I wanted to know how to check on the file, not how to wait; sorry for the misunderstanding.

The bitmap object was removed from the main thread's memory for various reasons.

Is there a standard way to do check if the file is being used, or should I just use a workaround?

Comment: If you are telling main thread to wait until background thread finishes, then why use the background thread at all?

Comment: I wanted to know how to check on the file, not how to wait; sorry for the misunderstanding. Naturally I'd use an asynctask with a progress dialog or something.

Comment: My point is that you don't have to check on the file. Use AsyncTask to save the bitmap and when done update UI. See AsyncTask docs to see how to do it. You don't have to start Threads manually. AsyncTask handles all this automatically.

Comment: I am using AsyncTask to save the file. I don't always know when it's done because the main activity might end before the AsyncTask is finished. For example, if user hits back button to exit the main activity, and then immediately launch the main activity again, it will try to load the file before the AsyncTask finish saving.

Comment: Yes this is a common problem. I solve it by sending a broadcast. Any interested Activity then registers to listen to it and updates the UI if one is received.

Comment: I am saving it in a background thread so the user can start editing another file immediately. If they start saving, then try to load the same file, I will tell them to wait. Now this is not a problem at all if I can hold on to a boolean that says "fileIsBusy". But if user restarts the app, loading the file will fail. I need to be able to check on the status of the file whenever I want, not just get notified when its done. That way I can tell the user, "wait a second, file is busy, don't touch anything." Hope that clears it up!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3717/discussion-between-li-w-and-peter-knego)

Comment: Ahh, got it. I'd make this simple - when saving just name the file in a specific way e.g. "tmp##original_name". Then rename it when done. That way any code will know file is being saved to just by looking at it's name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `FileObserver` class suits your needs perfectly. [Here is the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html). It's easy to use.  When a observed file is closed after writing, the `onEvent` callback is called with `CLOSE_WRITE` as the parameter.

Comment: That's the correct answer for observing the file change, but the wrong one in this context. OP has problem with wrong UI thread handling.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)to run a background thread and update UI when finished. It was designed for specifically this task.

Also note that you should never hog the UI thread (like waiting for background thread to finish) because this blocks UI interaction and your UI will be unresponsive or worse you might get an [ANR.](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html#anr)

Comment: Yeah I would use an AsyncTask to check on the file. Just wanted to know how to check :)

Comment: Huh? You dont have to check on the file. Just use AsyncTask to save the file (which automatically runs in background thread) and when this is done update the UI In `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Right. The file should be saved in an `AsyncTask`. that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Android's AsyncTask will be suitable for this problem:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You can update the bitmap in doInBackground, and then onPostExecute you can notify the main thread do draw it to canvas.

edit/what he said

Comment: Sometimes the main thread is destroyed too (configuration changed) so it goes like this: 1. background thread saving.  2. main thread destroyed.  3. main thread created, and attempt to load file.  4. file not loaded because it hasn't finished saving.